# How do I reset back the "select" button in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a drop down in my excel called "yes", "no" and "select" options for a category.
I also have  a reset option in the same excel. So basically the user should be able to enter the category name and select "yes"/"no" option. Once he hits the reset the button, this drop down should get back to "select" option. How do I get it done?

As of now, once I hit the reset button, it shows the previous yes/no selection done by the user.

Comment: What does reset button now ?

Comment: If it is data validation     :`range("A1")="select"`